# Creating multiple objects with same name through a loop

Tags: java, loops, object

I'm trying to create and use several instances of a class called Room in another class called TextGame. The TextGame class has an instance variable called numRooms, and the boolean expression of the loop ends at that instance variable. The only problem I'm having is that the loop creates an object with the same name as the last one. I'm not sure if that overrides the object resulting in only one object at the end of the loop.

Here is the method that contains the loop:

```
public void makeRooms(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < numRooms; i++){
        System.out.println("What riddle do you want in Room " + (i+1) + "?");
        String riddle = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the answer for that riddle?");
        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        Room room = new Room(riddle, answer);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can name the Room objects based on the value of i at each iteration?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an array of `Room`s

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160763/multiple-same-object-instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use a simple array. This can be easier in this case since you know the number of rooms.

```
Room[] roomArray=new Room[numRooms]; //This happens outside the for loop
```

Then inside the for loop, change the line starting with `Room room=new Room(`... to:

```
room[i]=new Room(riddle, answer);
```

Please note that your loop *must* start with 0, which it does here.

**Another** solution is to use an ArrayList. This is somewhat harder but more flexible if you don't know how many rooms you will add.

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms=new ArrayList<>(); //The brackets refer to generics
```

Then, in your for loop, add:

```
rooms.add(room);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your rooms into a `Collection` , could be a  `List<Room>` or you can use a Dictionary in java a `Map <Key,Value>` where the key is the number of room.